# TranslateAnimation - Image Disappearing when Animation is started

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I tried defining the animation in an xml file but it does not offer enough flexibility. Any ideas on how I can get this to work in code.

My image disappears and then reappears when the animation starts. Essentially, when I lift a finger, I would need the image to move back to its original position as a slow slide. this is not happening for some reason.

Java CODE:

```
chargeButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
        int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

        switch (event.getActionMasked()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                chargeButton.setLayoutParams(setPosition(x_cord, false));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                int x_start = x_cord;
                x_cord = 0;
                slowMove(x_start, x_cord, false);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});


}

public void slowMove(int x_start, int x_final, boolean pay)
{
Animation transAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(x_start, x_final, 0, 0);
transAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
transAnimation.setDuration(1000);
if (pay)
    payButton.startAnimation(transAnimation);
else
{
    chargeButton.clearAnimation();
    chargeButton.startAnimation(transAnimation);
}
}
```

I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to change the fromXdelta in my code itself.

Why don't you use the [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html#TranslateAnimation%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) itself?

```
 public TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
```

---

```
fromXDelta  Change in X coordinate to apply at the start of the animation
toXDelta    Change in X coordinate to apply at the end of the animation
fromYDelta  Change in Y coordinate to apply at the start of the animation
toYDelta    Change in Y coordinate to apply at the end of the animation
```

Comment: Using the constructor would be perfect. However, When I try using the constructor, my imageView disappears altogether. I am not sure why this is happening. 

I am inputting x_start, x_final, y_start and y_final as ints. Would this matter? Do you know why this would happen? Do you have working code of translateImage through a constructor which uses absolute positioning of the view?

Comment: int should matter. I can't say why you image disappears till I see your code.  Here is an [working example](http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2010/12/slide-up-down-translate.html)

Comment: Hey Reno.. I have updated my question to include my code. Any idea on why the image disappears?